# Routes with a dot in the parameter and constraints for it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have the a route which can have a period in its parameter. Here is what my route looks like:

```
put 'book/:book_name' => :create_record
```

If I pass `:book_name` as `'The End.'`, I get back an error with something like 'No route found'. Looking for it, I learnt that I need to add a constraint like `{:book_name => /[^\/]+/ }` for it to work.

So now, I can pass the values for `:book_name` as `'The End.'` or `'...'` or anything else with a period in it. However when I pass just one `'.'`, it again throws back on me with the same 'No routes found' error.

How can I handle this?

Comment: do you really need a route with just "."?

Comment: Yes :book_name is a string and it could have any characters. If couldn't find a solution, will update the requirements to have minimum characters more than 2 for a book_name since I noticed using '...' works where as '.' or '..' does not.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
{:book_name => /[^\/]+/ }
```

Try:

```
{:book_name => /[^\/]*/ }
```

`*` matches 0 or any number of times the preceding character.

Comment: Okay giving it a try.

Comment: Sorry this didn't help me much. I am still seeing the same results. :(

Comment: try `{:book_name => /.*/ }`

Comment: I am getting the same results for this as well. '.' and '..' doesn't work. Number of periods less than 3 does not work.

Comment: I think Rails has specific restrictions to block one/two dot characters

Comment: Thats sad. May be I will try passing the data in the request body instead of in URL.